# Highchart Dendogram in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, charts

i want to show a simple dendogram and i have uploaded a zip file having highchart.js, highchart-more, treegraph in stati c resource but still not working.

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";
import { loadScript, loadStyle } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import highchart from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/highchart";
import highcharttreegraph from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/highcharttreegraph";
import highcharttreemap from "@salesforce/resourceUrl/highcharttreemap";

export default class Highcharttest extends LightningElement {
  highChartInitialized = false;
  renderedCallback() {
    if (this.highChartInitialized) {
      return;
    }
    Promise.all([
      loadScript(this, highchart)
        .then(() => console.log("Highcharts loaded11111111111111"))
        .catch((error) =>
          console.log("Error in loading Highcharts11111111111111111" + error)
        ),
      loadScript(this, highcharttreemap)
        .then(() => console.log("Highcharts loaded3333333333"))
        .catch((error) =>
          console.log("Error in loading Highcharts333333333333" + error)
        ),
      loadScript(this, highcharttreegraph)
        .then(() => console.log("Highcharts loaded222222222"))
        .catch((error) =>
          console.log("Error in loading Highcharts222222222222" + error)
        ),
    ])
      .then(() => {
        console.log("High Charts Loaded in thennnnnnn");
        this.runHighcharts();
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log("Error occured thennnnnnn: ", error));
  }
  runHighcharts() {
    const container = this.template.querySelector(".container-class");
    window.Highcharts.chart(container, {
      title: { text: "Phylogenetic language tree" },
      series: [
        {
          type: "treegraph",
          keys: ["parent", "id", "level"],
          clip: false,
          data: [
            [undefined, "Proto Indo-European"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Balto-Slavic"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Germanic"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Celtic"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Italic"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Hellenic"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Anatolian"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Indo-Iranian"],
            ["Proto Indo-European", "Tocharian"],
            ,
          ],
          marker: {
            symbol: "circle",
            radius: 6,
            fillColor: "#ffffff",
            lineWidth: 3,
          },
          dataLabels: {
            align: "left",
            pointFormat: "{point.id}",
            style: {
              color: "#000000",
              textOutline: "3px #ffffff",
              whiteSpace: "nowrap",
            },
            x: 24,
            crop: false,
            overflow: "none",
          },
          levels: [
            { level: 1, levelIsConstant: false },
            { level: 2, colorByPoint: true },
            { level: 3, colorVariation: { key: "brightness", to: -0.5 } },
            { level: 4, colorVariation: { key: "brightness", to: 0.5 } },
            { level: 6, dataLabels: { x: 10 }, marker: { radius: 4 } },
          ],
        },
      ],
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Syed and welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. You should be as specific as possible when posting questions here to get the best help. In particular, your post needs to be more specific than "still not working". Are you getting an error? If so, please post the message. Add any additional information via **[edit]**.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got it finally! The js is correct, problem was with html, was using svg and changing it to div worked!!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to include the old and new versions of the markup in question.